# Getting form to fill on click

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    function autofillForm() { document.getElementbyId('add').getElementsByName('foo')[0].value = 'bar'; }
</script>

<form id="add">
    Foo<input name="foo" value="" />
</form>

<a onClick="autofillForm()">Click to fill</a>
```

I'm just trying to get it so that when I run the function, the form fills with "bar".  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('add').getElementsByName('foo').value = 'bar';
//---------------------------------------^ telltale sign that this is an array!
```

hence

```
document.getElementById('add').getElementsByName('foo')[0].value = 'bar';
```

---

**EDIT:** Of course, `getElementsByName()` is only supported on the document object itself, so it must be:

```
document.getElementsByName('foo')[0].value = 'bar';
```

Comment: 1) `getElementbyId()` must really be `getElementById()` (typo, JS is case-sensitive) and 2) `getElementsByName()` is only supported on the document object. See: http://jsfiddle.net/wqWNf/5/

Answer (score 1):

Since `document.getElementbyId('add').getElementsByName('foo')` is returning a NodeList (an array-like object), you need to do this to get the first one:

`document.getElementbyId('add').getElementsByName('foo')[0].value = 'bar';`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wqWNf/3/ doesn't work in jsFiddle, but it does when I take it out and put it in its own document.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName returns set of Elements
you need to get first of this array and set value on it

```
var elm = document.getElementbyId('add').getElementsByName('foo');
elm[0].value = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName() returns an array of matching elements. Even if there is only one of them.

Try something like

```
var fooElements = document.getElementbyId('add').getElementsByName('foo');
fooElements[0].value = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

first get the lements by name and then loop round with a for loop assigneing each element a value.

```
<script>
function autofillForm() { var eles = document.getElementsByName('foo'); for(var i=0; i<eles.length; i++){eles[i].value = 'bar';} }
</script>
```